# Parse proxy strings to array of objects

Tags: javascript, parsing, node.js, typescript, proxy

The goal of this module is to take in a string (user input, someone copy and pasting a large list of proxies) and parse it into an array of objects.

I appreciate **any and all** feedback, <s>but I'm specifically interested in improving the `stringToProxy` function.</s>

<s>Namely I'm unsure about mutating the string parameter, seems like there could be a better solution. And the way I'm declaring the proxy at the beginning of the function feels wrong to me (using `As`) but I couldn't think of any better solution. I also feel as though I may be overusing `string.split()`.</s>

Thanks for your time!

**Edit:**
Incorporated the `url` module as [Nazar](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35905/nazar) recommended. I'm happy with this solution but still taking feedback.

```
const { URL } = require("url");

interface Proxy {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    protocol: string;
    auth?: {
        username: string;
        password: string;
    };
}

function parse(string: string): Proxy[] {
    const rawArray = stringToArray(string);
    const fixedArray = rawArray.map((string) => fixProxyString(string));
    const proxyArray = fixedArray.map((string) => stringToProxy(string));
    return proxyArray;
}

function stringToArray(string: string): string[] {
    return string.trim().replace(/[ ,\n]+/g, ",").split(",");
}

function fixProxyString(string: string): string {
    return string.includes("://") ? string : `http://${string}`; //if user doesnt specify a protocol, default to http
}

function stringToProxy(string: string): Proxy {
    const url = new URL(string);
    return {
        host: url.hostname,
        port: url.port ? parseInt(url.port) : 80, //if proxy is 80 url will ignore it so i need to explicitly add it
        protocol: url.protocol.slice(0, -1), //removing the colon
        auth: url.username ? { username: url.username, password: url.password } : undefined
    };
}

export = parse;
```

Before edit:

```js
interface Proxy {
    host: string;
    port: number;
    auth?: {
        username: string;
        password: string;
    };
    protocol?: string;
}

function parse(string: string): Proxy[] {
    const rawArray = stringToArray(string);
    const proxyArray = rawArray.map((string) => stringToProxy(string));
    return proxyArray;
}

function stringToArray(string: string): string[] {
    return string.trim().replace(/[ ,\n]+/g, ",").split(",");
}

function stringToProxy(string: string) {
    const proxy = {} as Proxy;

    if (string.includes("://")) {
        const [protocol, remainder] = string.split("://");
        proxy.protocol = protocol;
        string = remainder;
    }
    if (string.includes("@")) {
        const [auth, remainder] = string.split("@");
        const [username, password] = auth.split(":");
        proxy.auth = { username, password };
        string = remainder;
    }
    const [host, port] = string.split(":");
    proxy.port = parseInt(port);
    proxy.host = host;

    return proxy;
}

export = parse;
```

Usage:

```
const parse = require("parse-proxy");

parse(`1.1.1.1:80, 2.2.2.2:80, 3.3.3.3:80`)

//result
[
  { host: '1.1.1.1', port: 80 },
  { host: '2.2.2.2', port: 80 },
  { host: '3.3.3.3', port: 80 }
]

parse(`https://user:pass@104.236.55.48:8080\nhttps://user:pass@213.105.29.14:3128`)

//result 
[
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    auth: { username: 'user', password: 'pass' },
    host: '104.236.55.48',
    port: 8080
  },
  {
    protocol: 'https',
    auth: { username: 'user', password: 'pass' },
    host: '213.105.29.14',
    port: 3128
  }
]
```

Comment: I would suggest using a built-in WHATWG API. You can get almost the same output by calling `require('url').parse` function.

Comment: Ah yes, that does the trick, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of small comments:

Don't call your parameter the same thing as its type `string: string`. This makes the code needlessly difficult to read - don't make the reader waste time wondering whether this `string` a type or the variable. Use `input`, `source` or something else that makes sense.

Don't shadow outer variables/arguments in arrow functions, again this harms readability `rawArray.map((string) => fixProxyString(string));`. Note that the parenthesis are optional for one parameter too. Consider instead:

```
function parse(input: string): Proxy[] {
    const rawArray = stringToArray(input);
    const fixedArray = rawArray.map(raw => fixProxyString(raw));
    const proxyArray = fixedArray.map(fixed => stringToProxy(fixed));
    return proxyArray;
}
```

I think (although not tested) that you can further simplify:

```
function parse(input: string): Proxy[] {
    return stringToArray(input)
        .map(fixProxyString)
        .map(stringToProxy);
}
```

You don't need to replace and then split here `return string.trim().replace(/[ ,\n]+/g, ",").split(",");`. You can just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by the regex directly.